# Visual Studio Code cannot debug typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I know this problem has been posted a lot of times but none of the solutions that I've found seem to help me. I'm missing something.

I'm using VSCode version 1.19.2 which has built in support for typescript debugging. When I try to run debugging I get an error:

```
Cannot launch program 'c:\devl\work\heroku\chatbot-tests\src\app.ts' because corresponding JavaScript cannot be found.
```

(My node version is 8.9.4, npm version is 5.6.0)

Here's what I've checked as part of the solution:

1. My .ts files are being compiled into .js files and .js.map files right next to them.
2. The .js files seem to have a correct sourcemap URL at the end
3. The .js.map files seem to have a correct .js file URL at the beginning
4. My VSCode launch.json has an outFiles property that points to the app.js file.

As for my configuration, here's my directory structure:

My directory structure:
[File directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLxIN.png)

My gulp file:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var ts = require("gulp-typescript");
var tsProject = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json");
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task("default", function () {
    return tsProject.src()
        .pipe(tsProject())
        .js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});
```

My tsconfig.json file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./built",
        "allowJs": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true
    },

    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

My launch.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "name": "debug node",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/app.ts",
            "request": "launch",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/dist/app.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The URL at the end of app.js:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

The beginning of app.js.map:

```
{"version":3,"names":[],"mappings":"","sources":["app.js"],"sourcesContent":["\"use strict...
```

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!